# Get non empty items in array map in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have react native Loop to fill the select Items like below

```
   const categorylist = arr.map((data, key) => {
      if (data != "") {
        return <Select.Item label={data} value={data} key={data} />;
      }
    });
```

I loop and use it like below , it works fine when array contains non empty values, but when there is empty values i get the error

**TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'child.props')**

```
   <Select>
     {categorylist2}
    </Select>
```

How do i send only non empty array items using map. please note i don't want **arr** to be affected as i need it unchanged in other functions.

Comment: you can also use `reduce` instead of map and filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the empty elements then `map` over the array `filter` returns.

Here's a contrived example to show you how it works.

```js
const arr = [undefined, 'Bob', '', 'Sally', 'Joe', '', null, 'Pam'];

// `filter` out the empty/null/undefined elements
// and then `map` over that filtered array
const out = arr
  .filter(el => el)
  .map(el => `<div>${el}</div>`);

document.body.innerHTML = out.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map through the array only if the array is not empty and use filter(Boolean) to filter out empty ones.

```
const newArr = arr.filter(Boolean);
const categorylist = (newArr.length > 0) && newArr.map((data, key) => {
    return <Select.Item label={data} value={data} key={data} />;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your map you do not return anything for empty values, which means null that's why you have the error. A map function should always return something.

Use filter before map like so:

arr.filter(data => data !== "").map(data => <Select.Item label={data} value={data} key={data} />)

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function.

> Using Array.filter() then Array.map() traverses the array twice, but
> you can achieve the same effect while traversing only once with
> Array.reduce(), thereby being more efficient.

More about it [here](https://Using%20Array.filter()%20then%20Array.map()%20traverses%20the%20array%20twice,%20but%20you%20can%20achieve%20the%20same%20effect%20while%20traversing%20only%20once%20with%20Array.reduce(),%20thereby%20being%20more%20efficient.)

```
const categorylist = arr.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
      if (current != "") {
        acc.push(<Select.Item label={current} value={current} key={current} />);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
    
    console.log(categorylist);
```